# filling a vector of vectors initialized with unspecified dimensions

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a 2d vector that is filled with '0's as it is initialized:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> grid(rows, std::vector<char>(cols, '0'));
```

however I would like to initialize it as an empty 2d vector with unspecified size:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>>grid;
```

and then fill it to achieve the same effect as the first statement. I do not think I can use `fill()` because it has no `.begin()` or `.end()` and I have been playing with for loops and `push_back` to no avail, usually get a segmentation fault error . I feel that what I am trying to do should be possible, and if it is what is the best way to go about doing it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: why don't you create a struct my_val{char val = '0';} and then do std::vector<std::vector<my_val>>grid;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use C++11 or higher, you can use the following overload of [`std::vector::resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value );
```

For your case, it will be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>>grid;

...

grid.resize(rows, std::vector<char>(cols, '0'));
```

Comment: I just started looking into resize, did not realize yet that it could also fill it! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with couple of for loops.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>>grid;
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    vector<char> v;
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        char ch;
        cin >> ch;
        v.push_back(ch);
    }
    grid.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: interesting... why are you using the cin object??

Comment: no reason, just an example of how you can populate the vector.

Comment: If you know exactly how many elements you're going to add (as you do in this case), you should `reserve` space in the vector outside of the loop to increase efficiency.